# sum sql with currently login user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

I have a problem with `sum` in SQL.

this is the case, when someone login in example `Untung Budi S. S.Kom` I want that sum sql to sum the "pilihan" column with condition `where idPertanyaan = '1' AND idDsn = "ID of the currently login user"`.

I don't know how to do that.

This is my SQL:

```
<?php 
$sql = "select sum(pilihan) from tbl_tampung where (idPertanyaan) = '1' AND (idDsn)= '<?php echo $_SESSION["user"]' ?> ";   

$q = mysql_query($sql);                 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q);                    
echo 'Jumlah dari pertanyaan : ' . $row[0];
?>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_*, it's deprecated, look into using PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "select sum(pilihan) from tbl_tampung where idPertanyaan = '1' AND idDsn= '".$_SESSION["user"]."'";
```

Comment: No problem. String concatenation on queries can get confusing with all the different single and double quotes, etc. glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

1) change this line `'<?php echo $_SESSION["user"]' ?>`

to

```
'$_SESSION["user"]'
```

2) create a connection with db

3) stop using `mysql*` extensions , they are deprecated , move to `mysqli*` or `pdo*` extensions